# Get DeviceContext of Entire Screen with Multiple Montiors

Tags: c#, pinvoke, gdi, multiple-monitors

I need to draw a line (with the mouse) over everything with C#. I can get a Graphics object of the desktop window by using P/Invoke:

DesktopGraphics = Graphics.FromHdc(GetDC(IntPtr.Zero));

However, anything I draw using this graphics object is only showing on the left monitor, and nothing on the right monitor. It doesn't fail or anything, it just doesn't show.

After I create the Graphics object, it shows the visible clip region to be 1680 x 1050 which is the resolution of my left monitor. I can only assume that it's only getting a device context for the left monitor. Is their a way to get the device context for both (or any number) monitors?

---

**EDIT 3/7/2009:
Additional information about the fix I used.**

I used the fix provided by colithium to come up with the following code for creating a graphics object for each monitor as well as a way to store the offset so that I can translate global mouse points to valid points on the graphics surface.

```
private void InitializeGraphics()
{
    // Create graphics for each display using compatibility mode
    CompatibilitySurfaces = Screen.AllScreens.Select(s => new CompatibilitySurface()
        {
            SurfaceGraphics = Graphics.FromHdc(CreateDC(null, s.DeviceName, null, IntPtr.Zero)),
            Offset = new Size(s.Bounds.Location)
        }).ToArray();
}

private class CompatibilitySurface : IDisposable
{
    public Graphics SurfaceGraphics = null;
    public Size Offset = default(Size);

    public PointF[] OffsetPoints(PointF[] Points)
    {
        return Points.Select(p => PointF.Subtract(p, Offset)).ToArray();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (SurfaceGraphics != null)
            SurfaceGraphics.Dispose();
    }
}

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateDC(string lpszDriver, string lpszDevice, string lpszOutput, IntPtr lpInitData);
```

Comment: Ok, now, this is really, really odd. Your code works for FillRectangle() but not for DrawString and other methods of SurfaceGraphics object. DrawString always draws on Primary display, no meter what SurfaceGraphics I am using, but FillRectangle behaves correctly. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/253023-docking-window-problem) is a link to another person that had the same problem.  It was solved with a call to:

```
CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"),NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

which will return a DC to all monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Following URL to get EnumDisplayMonitor may solve your problem

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610(VS.85).aspx)

To retrieve information about all of the display monitors, use code like this:

EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MyInfoEnumProc, 0);  One more URL given at
 [MSJ](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0697/monitor/monitor.aspx)

Comment: You were also correct. I used EnumDisplayMonitors to get the device name which I then handed off to CreateDC. Thanks!